# Show that there exist $n, m \in \mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$ such that $\alpha^n = \beta^m$, without computing $n, m$.

Tags: number-theory, measure-theory, algebraic-number-theory, algebraic-groups

Let $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{13})$, $ \alpha = (3+\sqrt{13})/2$ and $\beta = 23382 + 6485\sqrt{13}$.

Show that there exist $n, m \in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$ such that $\alpha^n = \beta^m$, without computing $n, m$.

How would I show this? The norms I believe are both -1, so they must differ by a unit, but I do not know how to proceed, can I use Dirichlet's theorem or not? Any hints would be welcome

Comment: I believe this is false.  Taking the norm down to $\mathbb Q$ shows that $\alpha$ is a unit in the ring of integers of $K$, while $\beta$ is not.

Comment: The norm is the map $N:K \rightarrow \mathbb Q$ given by $N(x) = x \sigma(x)$, where $\sigma$ is given by $\sigma(x+\sqrt{13}y) = x-\sqrt{13}y$.

Comment: The norms for both are -1. So it can't be false.

Comment: Mathe Student: But you ask in your post: "What is the norm"? So please edit your post to add that you claim the norms for both are -1?

Comment: Sorry about this, I have edited this in now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Dirichlet's unit theorem, there is an element $x \in \mathcal O_K^{\ast}$ such that every unit in $\mathcal O_K^{\ast}$ is uniquely expressible as $\pm x^n$.  Write $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in this form.